# AutoMapper how to ignore exception when getting a property that throws exception?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a source object which derives from System.Data.DataRow whose string properties will throw exceptions on Get if the underlying value is DBNull

```
private static void CreateMappings(IMapperConfiguration config)
{
    config.CreateMap<SrcRow, DestDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Error_Text, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(row =>
        {
            try
            {
                // the getter of this string property throws exception if internal value is DBNull
                return row.error_text;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }))
    ;
```

}

All the source and destination properties are string.  The source object is a wrapper around a DataRow and each property gets a particular row value.  If the row value is DBNull value, the property getter throws an exception.  How can I achieve this code but for all members of the destination type instead of copy/pasting this code for each member?

Comment: Don't use exceptions as control flow. You can easily convert it into a conditional return.

Comment: Even if I try to:
var x = row.error_text;

it'll still throw.  I have to catch.  This is not a field I can inspect using:
if (row.error_text == null)

Comment: property looks something like this:
public string error_text{
   get{//if underlying value is DBNull, throw new Exception()}
   set{}
}

Comment: SrcRow is not my object.  but i'm mapping from SrcRow to my DestDto

Comment: I'm struggling to find a polite way to say that it's [beeep] to throw an exception in a getter. Is whoever made this willing and available to change it on short notice into decently returning null or an empty string?

Comment: This is a temp-table proxy component generated by Progress O4gl.  Not my component.  I agree, why throw in a getter?

Comment: Progress? That used to be the most brilliant software out there. They had LINQ of sorts when .Net wasn't even conceived yet. Now they're making code generators producing this?? Well, there's not much you can do then.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Automapper provides this:

```
private static void CreateMappings(IMapperConfiguration config)
{
  config.CreateMap<SrcRow, DestDto>()
  .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.ResolveUsing(
    ...
  ); // or use opt.Condition()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using `ForAllMembers()` method and create a condition to map the value only if the source doesn't throw an exception:

```
config.CreateMap<SrcRow, DestDto>().ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition(rc => 
{
    try  { return rc.SourceValue != null; } // Or anything, just try to get the value. 
    catch { return false; }
}));
```